# obtaining cell value from a gridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image]

I have such a gridline. I want to obtain selected value.

```
double yinitial =Convert.ToDouble(dataGridViewHagerDWSP.Rows[1].Cells[8].Value);
MessageBox.Show(yinitial.ToString());
```

It doesn't work. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `Convert.ToDouble(dataGridViewHagerDWSP.Rows[0].Cells[7].Value)`? I guess the row/column indices are 0-based.

Comment: yes, it worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Convert.ToDouble(dataGridViewHagerDWSP.Rows[0].Cells[7].Valu‌​e)` will work in this case since row and column indices are zero-based.